# Every $\ell^p$ space with $p\ne 2$ has a subspace without a Schauder basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, schauder-basis

Rajendra Bhatia's *Notes on Functional Analysis* (Texts and Readings in Mathematics), [Pg. $14$](https://books.google.com/books?id=x_JdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14) states (without proof) that:

> Every $\ell^p$ space ($1\le p \le \infty)$ with $p\ne 2$ has a *subspace* without a Schauder basis.

where $\ell^p$ denotes the sequence space with the $p$-norm.

1. What is the proof of this fact? I have been trying for a while now, and it seems more difficult than I had imagined.
2. Also, I would be interested to see why every subspace of $\ell^2$ has a Schauder basis.

P.S. If the proof is doable with some hints, then just hints would be great too!

**Update:** The proof of the main assertion is found in *Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's Classical Banach Spaces I and II*, as mentioned by David Mitra in the comments.

Comment: See the wikipedia article on Schauder basis and look for the section on "Relation to Fourier series". This might be a counter-example to the assertion.

Comment: I don't see how that is related. Could you elaborate? Note that it is enough to produce **one subspace** of $\ell^p$ without a Schauder basis. Many other subspaces may have a Schauder basis - doesn't matter.

Comment: It is not easy. Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's *Classical Banach Spaces I and II* contain a proof. (The stronger assertion, in fact, that they have subspaces without the approximation property.)

Comment: Thanks, David. I do not have access to that book right now. Would you be kind enough to sketch a proof outline, or give some idea on how to proceed? Also, what is the **approximation property**?

Comment: You can google AP. [Here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760833) is a link to a proof for $1\le p <2$. As I said, the proof is (far from) easy; I don't have the time to attempt to outline it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to question (1) is in the comment by @DavidMitra: You can refer to Lindenstrauss' and Tzafriri's *Classical Banach Spaces I and II* for a proof that every $\ell^p$ space with $p \neq 2$ admits a subspace without a Schauder basis.

The answer to question (2) is far easier: note that every subspace of $\ell^2$ is a separable inner product space. Since every separable inner product space admits a (countable) orthonormal basis (e.g. @mechanodroid answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2709563/671710)), you can take this orthonormal basis as your Schauder basis.